# Are unlocked phones upgradable to 7.8

Tags: settings

For some weird reason, Samsung has stopped offering Omnia W in India and launched Omnia M.

Omnia W(A.K.A. Focus flash on at&t) is much better and I am interested in buying the same. This device is available on eBay.in. But, its an unlocked phone from at&t with the logo on head.

My question is, whether this unlocked device is upgrable to 7.8 in future or will it stop working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there will be an update available but it is highly unlikely it will be among the first devices to receive this update. But the update will be available.

Comment: While I agree, do you have a source? I believe MS said that the update will not go through carriers and will be available to everyone, but I am not sure that they have released a list of phone models that will actually get it.

Comment: Yes, thats what i was thinking. Since the update will be available through zune, i think it hardly concerns the carrier